# Keeping last seen values in a summary table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

**parameters** keeps all the para_ids and their names and is always updated to have all parameters in it.

```
CREATE TABLE `parameters` (
  `para_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`para_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_parameters_name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**processing** is holding a chunk of data every 5 minutes.

```
CREATE TABLE `processing` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t_ns` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `para_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` varchar(1024) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `isanchor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `data` (`para_id`,`t_ns`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I want to keep a table **actual_values** with the last seen values that each parameter (if it occurred in processing) had. The para_ids are updated with an INSERT IGNORE before the update. Currently I have those queries:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO actual_values (para_id) (SELECT DISTINCT para_id FROM parameters);

UPDATE  actual_values a
JOIN processing p ON a.para_id = p.para_id
SET a.value = (SELECT p.value FROM processing p WHERE a.para_id = p.para_id ORDER BY t_ns DESC LIMIT 1);
```

I feel like this is not the optimal way to go, it takes quite long. Do you guys have better suggestions?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Because I throw away everything in processing once in a while and get new data, but still want to be able to see what the last values for each parameter were before.

Comment: The way I read your update stmt is that you have `a`, `p1`, and `p2` and that you are not using `p1` at all

Comment: p1 is used to gather all the possible parameters that can land in a. p2 holds the data, of which I try to find the last seen value for each parameter .